# Envio de XML para webservice

Tags: java, web-service, xml, asmx

Estou precisando saber como fazer envio de XML para um webservice de um cliente. Como sou bem novo nisso, dei uma pesquisada em algumas fontes e encontrei um código bem simples de *java*. Queria saber se está tudo correto:

```
package Envio;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
//import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class ConsumirWebServicePorRequisicaoXML {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws SOAPException, IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String requestSoap;

    requestSoap = "MEU XML";

    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

    String url = "MEU LINK ASMX do WEBSERVICE"; //url do webservice

    MimeHeaders headers = new MimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

    SOAPMessage msg = messageFactory.createMessage(headers, (new ByteArrayInputStream(requestSoap.getBytes())));

    SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(msg, url);
    Document xmlRespostaARequisicao=soapResponse.getSOAPBody().getOwnerDocument();

    System.out.println(passarXMLParaString(xmlRespostaARequisicao,4)); //imprime na tela o xml de retorno.
}
public static String passarXMLParaString(Document xml, int espacosIdentacao){
    try {
        //set up a transformer
        TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        transfac.setAttribute("indent-number", new Integer(espacosIdentacao));
        Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        //create string from xml tree
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xml);
        trans.transform(source, result);
        String xmlString = sw.toString();
        return xmlString;
    }
    catch (TransformerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Por razões óbvias, eu omiti o XML e o link do ASMX do webservice por conterem informações um pouco mais sigilosas. Mas eu já consegui validar o formato do XML e também possuo o link do webservice.

A ideia é que essa aplicação em JAVA seja executada uma vez ao dia ou uma vez por semana e faça o envio de vários XML pra esse webservice (depois eu mudo o código pra ele fazer o envio de mais de um XML).

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente a abordagem esta correta, basicamente você está criando uma requisição SOAP, adicionando os parametros no corpo da requisição onde um deles será o XML convertido em String e disparando a requisição.

Se efetivamente vai funcionar só testando mesmo, pois muita coisa pode variar.

Oq você pode fazer pra testar fora do Java é usar ferramentas como o SOAPUI para testar o serviço caso dê algum erro no Java, pois assim você valida se o problema é o codigo, a requisição ou o serviço.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Vinicius. Sim, eu já validei com a ajuda do SOAPUI. Precisava mesmo só saber se a programação em JAVA estava correta.